# Can't search the help center from meta, or see the error message

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, popup

Steps to see a shy popup:

1. Go to the ["**contact us**" page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) from meta.
2. Click on the textbox under "**Search the Help Center"**.
3. Bang your head on your keyboard.
4. Press enter or click the <kbd>**search**</kbd> button.

Result:

> [image: SHY POPUP]

Moreover, the search doesn't work either!

<sup><sub>I am not responsible for any damage that happens to your keyboard or your head when performing step 3 :p</sub></sup>

Comment: I can reproduce without step 3 for those who don't have a physical keyboard.

Comment: Inspecting that popup: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://stackoverflow.com/help/search-inline. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://meta.stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Step 4 was hard to reach. I am unable to reproduce anything.

Comment: @TravisJ: did you bang your head on the keyboard, as per instruction? I took it as meaning "enter anything random", I did not dare banging my iPad. Reproducable with that, by the way.

Comment: @Jongware - Unfortunately everything I applied step 3 to broke. After finding a working keyboard I was able to reproduce the issue using your updated set of instructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this *never* worked on child metas. It's been around for a couple of years and only now reported.

Anyhow, fixed in the next build.

Comment: Q: when will the next build go out? I just ran into what looks like the same problem, but don't want to report it if the fix is already in the pipeline.

Comment: They usually have a few deployments every day. Check the version at the bottom of the page. I can't help any more than that as I've not worked for SO in years.